# How can I pass a specific output only to another function in C?

Tags: c, char, user-defined-functions

So i have been working on a board game where when the player surrender, automatically from another function, his/her score should have a +1 and the other player will not have a score yet. The problem is how can I output that when the player say y or Y, it will already add up without asking again on the function of the score if he/she wants to surrender. Im still new in C programming and passing functions confused me a bit.

```
#include<stdio.h>
char SurrenderPlayer1(int Player1, int Player2, char Surrender)
{
    do
    {
    printf("(Y/N)Want to surrender? ");  
    scanf("%s", &Surrender);
    
    switch (Surrender){
        case 'y': 
        case 'Y':   
            printf("\n\tPlayer %d surrendered.  player %d, won!", Player1, Player2);
            break;
        case 'n': 
        case 'N':   
            printf("\tContinue Playing\n");
            break;
        }               
    }while (Surrender=='y' && Surrender=='Y' || Surrender=='n' && Surrender=='N');
}

char SurrenderPlayer2(int Player2, int Player1, char Surrender)
{
    do
    {
    printf("(Y/N)Want to surrender? ");  
    scanf("%s", &Surrender);
    
    switch (Surrender){
        case 'y': 
        case 'Y':   
            printf("\nPlayer %d surrendered. player %d, won!", Player2, Player1);
            break;
        case 'n': 
        case 'N':   
            printf("Continue Playing\n");
            break;
        }               
    }while (Surrender=='y' && Surrender=='Y' || Surrender=='n' && Surrender=='N');
}

int Scores(int Score1, int Score2)
{
    int Player1, Player2;
    char Surrender;
    
    printf ("!!!Match Scores!!!:");

    if (SurrenderPlayer1(Player1, Player2, Surrender)=='y'||'Y')
        Score1+=1;
    else(SurrenderPlayer2(Player2, Player1, Surrender)=='y'||'Y');
        Score2+=1;
        
    printf ("\nPlayer 1 - %d", Score1);
    printf ("\nPlayer 2 - %d", Score2);
    
    return 0;
}
int main(){
    int Score1=0, Score2=0;
    int Player1, Player2; 
    char Surrender;
    
    SurrenderPlayer1(Player1, Player2, Surrender);
    SurrenderPlayer2(Player2, Player1, Surrender);
    Scores(Score1, Score2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:
(Y/N)Want to surrender? y

Player 1 surrendered. Player 2, won!

//Clear screen//

!!!Match Scores!!!

Player 1 - 0

Player 2 - 1

Comment: Aside: What format specifier do we use for a character? Is it %s or %c?

Comment: You want that the `Surrender` functions don't ask the player whether the player wants to surrender unless it is for the first time. Do I understand correct? OR maybe you could explain it step by step for better understanding of others.